# Access Delete command in C#.NET generates "No value given for one or more required parameters"

Tags: c#, .net, ms-access

Here is the DELETE string:

```
string command1str = "DELETE FROM Person WHERE personID = '" + personID + "' ;";
```

The semicolon seems to not matter one way or the other.  The error occurs upon execution of the following:

```
OleDbCommand command1 = new OleDbCommand(command1str, connection);
command1.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

The second line generates the exception.  I do not know why.

Thanks.

Comment: Use parameterized query instead: `DELETE FROM Person WHERE personID = ?` and `command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PersonID", personID);`

Comment: What is the data type of personID in the Access database? Likely it will just work when you remove the single quotes, if personID is an integer or autonumber (`string command1str = "DELETE FROM Person WHERE personID = " + personID + " ;";`)

Answer (score 0):

Likely, `personID` is null or empty.

To troubleshoot the error, you could set a breakpoint after the line where you define the SQL command, copy the command and try running it in Access manually.